# iPhone App Icon shows white background

Tags: ios, mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working on a iOS application. My app icons has transparent background but when app installed on iPhone it shows white background.

Here is my app icon you can see the white borders:

[image]

How I can fit this icon?

Comment: its ok now khan sab?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have transparent background for app icons.
I suggest you to read the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) about icons. Explanation from these guidelines about transparency :

> **Avoid transparency.** An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s
>   boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use
>   transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can
>   appear to float on a dark background, which tends to look especially
>   unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

Answer (score 3):

**Pre-rendered icons on iOS**

By default, iOS will modify the icon graphic you supply to add rounded corners, a drop shadow, and a reflective shine. The graphics here shows the before (left) and after (right) effects of this transformation. Apple recommends that your icon graphic have 90-degree corners, does not apply any shine or gloss, and does not use any alpha transparency.

[image]  [image]

You cannot prevent the rounded corners or drop shadow from being applied. But you can override the reflective shine by providing a "prerendered" icon and making a change in the tiapp.xml file. You might do so to apply your own shine effects. To prevent the default shine from being applied, update the following key in the tiapp.xml to have the value true.

`<prerendered-icon>true</prerendered-icon>`

Please read more from  appc Doc http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-Pre-renderediconsoniOS

Comment: abada, your answer is perfect, but I think that Apple is not adding a shine effect anymore on app icons with iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected. You can see this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html) that explains how you should design your icon to avoid this white background

For the icon sizes, please check the first row of this [table](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2).